# render Object with Object as value in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, ejs

i've an object like the folllowing that i'm passing into the ejs template:

```
 { 
    course1: { last4: '4242', name: 'Course 1', paid: true },
    course2: { last4: '3155', name: 'Course 2', paid: true },
    course3: { last4: '4242', name: 'Course 3', paid: true } 
}
```

and i'm passing it through like this:

```
 res.render("user", {                
        courses: myCourses,               
});
```

I want to render the object inside the page, i tried something like this:

```
            <% if(courses){  %>
                <%= courses %>
                <% Object.entries(courses).forEach(course =>{ %>

             <p>hello</p>

            <%= course %>


            <% }) %>
            <% }else{ %>
                <p>hello1</p>
                <% }%>
```

this is the result:
[image: object result in browser]

this is what i expect:
[image: expected result]

so in the last example you see that i just get the objects key and not the values.
how can i also render (or access) the values?
thanks

Comment: We don’t really see. Can you show the HTML it renders, and what you would like it to render instead? (You’ll need to start off by not using the comma operator – or maybe it acts as an argument separator in EJS, giving you the first value instead of the last – so `<%= course %>, <%= name %>, …`, but apart from that it’s not clear what you want.)

Comment: @Ry- ok, just did.

Comment: Thanks for adding the current result. What do you want it to look like instead? (e.g. edit the HTML manually to show)

Comment: @Ry- added the expected result image, note that i'll still change a bit the html, i just want the key and all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of the array returned by `Object.entries` is a `[key, value]` array. With your existing code, `course[0]` is the current key, `course[1].last4` is the `last4` field of the current object, and so on.

I’d write it with at least one level of destructuring, like you originally had:

```
<% if (courses) {  %>
    <% for (const [key, course] of Object.entries(courses)) { %>
        <%= key %>
        <%= course.last4 %>
        <%= course.name %>
        <%= course.paid %>
    <% } %>
<% } else { %>
    <p>hello1</p>
<% } %>
```